# SML - Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [circularity]

Tags: sml, smlnj

Consider the following code  :

```
fun g(a) =
let     fun h(b)=g(a) 
in  h end;
```

When I run it in SML , I get :

```
- fun g(a) =
= let   fun h(b)=g(a)
= in    h end;
stdIn:55.5-57.10 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function re
sult type [circularity]
  expression:  'Z -> 'Y
  result type:  'Y
  in declaration:
    g = (fn a => let val <binding> in h end)
```

I can't understand the problem here : `g(a)` return `h` , but
I don't see any specific return value in the declaration `fun g(a)` (i.e. nothing like 
`fun g(a):int`) , so why the error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `g` has one parameter it has type `'X -> 'Y`.

`h(b) = g(a)` means that `h` and `g` must have the same result type `'Y`,
and `h` has the type `'Z -> 'Y`.

Thus, `g(x)`, for any x of type `'X`, must have type `'Y`.
But the return value of `g(x)` is `h`, which has type `'Z -> 'Y`.
This means that `'Y` must be the same type as `'Z -> 'Y`, which is impossible.

As SML says, `'Z -> 'Y` (the type of `h`) doesn't agree with `'Y` (the type of `g(a)`).

If you try to work it out by hand, you'll find that

```
g 1
```

would be a function `h` such that

```
h 3
```

is the value of

```
g 1
```

which is a function `h` such that...

and so on, indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

ML type inference system first identified your function g as an expression which takes a 'Z and returns 'Y. But then it sees that the result type of g is just 'Y and also which is the result type of earlier binding h. It can be expected to see binding of type Z -> Z->Y . However your function closure has an environment which is itself. So it is like binding g like this.

```
fun g a= g
```

ML type inference can not guess the types if your closure has an environment which is also itself.

You can declare these functions as follows.

```
fun g(a) =
    let     
    fun h(b)=g(a) 
    in  
    h(a)
    end;
```

It is like

```
fun g a = g a
```

This time your closure has just a body of itself. But it makes no sense...just an example of why you are getting a circularity error.

Comment: And then, you have a function that promises to return anything you want. But only if and when it returns .....

Comment: Do you agree with the explanation above? I will be really happy if you criticize of my understanding of the closures

Comment: no problem here, I absolutly agree wih you, but wanted to add that a function like `g a = g a` does not make any sense - or does it in SML?

Comment: No it is just an example. Yes it makes no sense.